# compare value when it matches one column value PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have 2 tables in PowerBI where I would like to compare value when it matches one column value.

Table 1

```
Number  Code
111      aa
222      bb
333      cc
```

Table 2

```
Number  Code
111      aa
222      bc
222      bb
333      ff
666      gg
```

Now what I would like to do is to compare the code when the Number Matches. Means the Output should look like in a comparison column-

```
Number  Code  Result
111      aa    Matches
222      bc    Not Matches
222      bb    Matches
333      ff    Not Matches
666      gg    Unknown
```

Do anyone knows any solution to solve this challenge!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to create a relationship between the tables and create a calculated column to one of them. The calculated column DAX should be something like:

```
Result = IF('Table 1'[Code] == 'Table 2'[Code], "Matches", "Not Matches")
```

Other way would be to create a calculated table based on both tables with DAX Summarize-function, create relationships to this calculated table and create a similar calculated column or a measure as above.

More information about relationships in Power Bi [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-create-and-manage-relationships) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-many-to-many-relationships)

Comment: I'm sorry if I didn't answer the question. What's the problem exactly, what did I miss? Maybe add some screenshots to make it more clear?

Answer (score 0):

This might work:
"Result = IF('Table 1'[Code] = 'Table 2'[Code]; "Matches"; "Not Matches")"